# How are Kuberenetes secrets stored on Amazon EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I set up a managed Kubernetes cluster via Amazon EKS. Now I’m wondering whether Kubernetes Secrets are stored securely (at rest and transit) by default or if there is additional configuration necessary.

The [relevant Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kms-provider/#enabling-the-kms-supported-by-your-cloud-provider) are not really helpful in this constellation l, all they say is that secret encryption depends on the cloud provider.

Any help, links or samples are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It appears the answer is yes, they are encrypted at rest, but this is hearsay. There's an open [github issue](https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/263) on this topic, and nobody else can find definitive docs stating this, either.